# JPA composite primary key generation of id regarding value of other fields

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I'm kind a newbie in JPA and I'm starting my first project where I need to use it.

I have a table of services and each service belongs to one service type. What I'd like to have as primary key is a composed ID with the service ID and the service type ID. The first one should be generated regarding the value of the last one, so we can have more than one service with the same service ID or with the same service tipe ID, but not both. That is, the service ID should be generated sequentially for each existing service type.

Is there any mechanism in JPA that supports this kind of value generation? If not, what is the best approach for that? I can define service ID as unique and drop service type ID from the primary key but it seems to me that if I follow this approach the relation between services and services types is not correctly expressed.

As JPA implementation I'm using Hibernate.